# Is there a way to rebuild Python Subversion bindings on Linux?

Tags: python, svn, centos, swig

I'm running Trac on a CentOS 5 host and it was running horribly slow. I tried installing Python 2.6 from the EPEL (plus mod_wsgi) and it is more responsive but I now get:

```
Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (Unsupported version control system "svn": No module named svn). Look in the Trac log for more information.
```

at the top of each page. I know it is because the SWIG bindings for Python to talk to SVN aren't installed, but I can't find a way to rebuild them. The subversion package from CentOS includes bindings for Python 2.4, but EPEL doesn't rebuild subversion or package the bindings separately. I could install Subversion from source, but I'd rather stick with packages wherever possible. Also, if I do try to build from source then I get "An appropriate version of sqlite could not be found" and haven't been able to resolve it yet (even though I'm using an identical version number to the one that comes pre-packaged with CentOS).

Is there a way of either just rebuilding the SWIG bindings or installing a package that I'm not aware of to give me the Python 2.6 bindings for Subversion?

Thanks.

Comment: This would be better suited to [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Perhaps you could build a custom RPM with the new versions of the source?

Comment: @Troubadour: Sorry, it probably does. I forgot there was a Linux/Unix site and was weighing up Stackoverflow as programming vs ServerFault as a Subversion/server issue.

Comment: @noufal-ibrahim: I could, but that basically gives me the same issues as building from source - I've got to maintain Subversion. If I can just rebuild the SWIG bindings once and have that as the only self-maintained bit then I'd rather do that.